# Assigning A Random value 3D Array to an Array of class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a class with three fields:

```
public class CCTest {
    public double f;
    public double[][][] x;
    public double counter;
}
```

I am trying to assign a random number to it. I have the method below for random data generation:

```
public static double[][][] getRandomX(int x, int y, int z) {
    double[][][] result = new double[x][y][z];
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
                result[k][j][i] = r.nextDouble();
             }
        }
    }
    // System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    return result;
 }
```

As for the issue. I have for example an array with 5 `CCTest`-objects:

```
CCTest[] cls = new CCTest[5];
```

How can I assign a random number to each of the 5 `CCTest`-objects?
I tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Size =5; i++) {  
    cls[i].x = new double[this.c][this.D][this.Size];
    for (int j = 0; j < this.D; j++) {
        cls[i].X= getRandomX(this.c, this.D, this.Size);
    }
```

The result should have following structure:

```
X(:,:,1) =

0.8909    0.5472
0.9593    0.1386

X(:,:,2) =

0.1493    0.8407
0.2575    0.2543
```

But the code did not produce it. Could anyone guide me to a solution, please?

Comment: What is your current result?

Comment: @chris the result is Null

Comment: if you're getting an indexoutofboundsexception within your 3dprint method then you should put the code for it in your question so that we can debug it.

Comment: @Chris I could not put the code in proper format in comment box ,  please could you explain  how can i do that. I used the ( ` ) but did not work.

Comment: Put your code in between two ` marks. For example `insert_code_here`. Or if you can't do that then edit your question by pressing the "edit" button at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't made any `CCTest`-instances.

So after you make the `CCTest[] cls = new CCTest[5];` the five `CCTest`-objects are `null`. You should create them if they don't exist yet:

```
CCTest[] cls = new CCTest[5];

for (int i = 0; i < (Size = 5); i++) {
    // We create a new CCTest-instance if it doesn't exist yet:
    if(cls[i] == null){
        cls[i] = new CCTest();
    }

    cls[i].x = new double[this.c][this.D][this.Size];
    for (int j = 0; j < this.D; j++) {
        cls[i].x = getRandomX(this.c, this.D, this.Size);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create them first, and then do the for-loop to assign the random doubles:

```
CCTest[] cls = new CCTest[5];
for (int i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
    cls[i] = new CCTest();
}

for (int i = 0; i < (Size = 5); i++) {
    cls[i].x = new double[this.c][this.D][this.Size];
    for (int j = 0; j < this.D; j++) {
        cls[i].x = getRandomX(this.c, this.D, this.Size);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used  3D print method , but iam getting error which is : IndexOutOfBound :3Dprint(cls[i].x)